# wpf mvvm datagrid selectedrow

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, mvvm

after some google around, I just figured out that there is no one that is using 100% MvvM pattern to get the ToolKit DataGrid events !

Is that impossible or what ? I see too much people using the code-behind...

How can I get the SelectedRow or dblClick events using mvvm ?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an attached property of type ICommand. When the property value changes, hook/unhook the click event handler in which you can execute the command.